# Android performance issue with inflating a custom view

Tags: android, performance, android-inflate

I ave created a custom view of a month tile grid that is displayed for a particular year.

it holds 12 date tiles representing each month.
it looks like this:

[image]

each tile is inflated using the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/date_tile_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/date_tile_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/dateTile"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/date_tile_height"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/date_tile_width"
                android:textColor="#B7BAAB"
                />

        <com.endilo.views.LetterSpacingTextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTileCenterLabel"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/date_tile_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/date_tile_width"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:scaleX="0.6"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="#BCBFAF"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/dateTileCheckbox"
            android:button="@drawable/check_green"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTileMonthLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:text="Jan"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

it takes around  30-50ms to inflate each `DateTile` when talking about a single year which is a single `DateGridView` it task ~ 40*12 = 0.5 secs to inflate a single year.
I need to inflate at leas 3 pages because i use this in a page adapter that displayed the previous and next year.

is there any way to make the inflation faster or reuse the same layout to create 12 separate date tiles like this faster ?